# How to add a "Agree to terms and conditions" checkbox on the Stripe checkout screen?

Tags: stripe-payments, form-submit

I'm trying to add a terms and conditions checkbox on Stripe Checkout, so that the pay button would remain disabled until the user clicks on the checkbox to agree to our terms. It would look something like this:

[image]

I can't find any solution to this. There is a Stripe plugin for Wordpress that does this, but we do not use Wordpress so cannot use the stripe plugin. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Stripe Checkout does not have any configurable options for adding a terms of service link with an acceptance checkbox. You would need to build that input on your own and include the checkbox as a precursor to [redirecting to Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment#redirect-customers). You can read more on what's customizable in Checkout here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a new feature or it was when you asked, but there is an example in the documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/customization#collect-a-terms-of-service-agreement

So basically, add to the checkout creation:

```js
    consent_collection: {
      terms_of_service: "required",
    },
```

And configure the Privacy policy, Terms of service, Support website .... links.